# PHP Ternary Operator not working for this code

Tags: php

i would like to use Ternary Operator for the below code..

```
<?php 
if($users['active'] == 1 ) 
{ 
    echo 'Yes'; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo 'No'; 
} 
?>
```

i tried using this code and it does not work..

```
<?php ($users['active'] == 1) ? echo "Yes" : echo "No";  ?>
```

what is wrong?

Comment: see, this is why you shouldnt be using it.

Comment: what happens when you run it? does it always end up at "no"?

Comment: @Gordon: The ternary operator is amongst the most useful of tools in modern languages.  Just because some people have not yet learnt how to use it, does not invalidate its use.

Comment: @Orbling a ternary operator is the most useless of all the operators since it is basically only a shorthand if/else. As such, I can easily live without it but definitely not with any of the others. And given that apparently a lot of people fail to understand [the concept of expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php), it is good advice to disadvice it's usage.

Comment: @Gordon agreed it is just the shorthand, but does it not beautify the code? and moreover if i use it i have somewhat little less code to write.

Comment: @Ibrahim on the contrary. It's not beautifying your code, but obfuscating it for anything but the simplest usecase of assigning a scalar. the instant you put any complex expressions into a ternary statement, let alone stack multiple ternaries, you are making a complete mess.

Comment: @Gordon: I disagree entirely, it does make code more elegant in my opinion,  Whether or not it is a complete mess is a matter of opinion.  It makes it closer to a mathematical expression - programmers are meant to be mathematicians.  With decent whitespace it is far clearer than a bunch of `ifs`.

Comment: @Orbling we will have to agree to disagree on all parts

Comment: @Gordon: Even that programmers should be mathematicians?

Comment: @Orbling especially on that part. Programmers shouldn't be bothered with proving that 1 > 0 or with inventing new efficient algorithms. Leave that to the CompScis. Programmers are implementors.

Comment: @Gordon: Not sure I could disagree with you more strongly on that.  Comp Sci is required for programming of any complexity.  It is like saying that any other engineer need not know how to do the calculations of their field.  Your definition of a programmer is obviously vastly lesser than mine.  I would suggest *script kiddy* as a replacement.

Comment: @Orbling like I said, we have to disagree on all parts :)

Comment: I second entirely what @Gordon says. A program needs to be accessible and maintainable over everything else. It's not the place to express mathematical genius (unless that is the subject matter of the program.)

Comment: Re *ScriptKiddies*: [The Story of Mel - a *real* programmer](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html)

Comment: @Orbling: CompSci is to Physics as Programming is to Engineering.  You need to understand the concepts, but Programming is about the practical implementations whereas CompSci is about theoretical problem solving and research.  There's a fair amount of overlap between them, but they are distinct disciplines.  And to be fair, the majority of recent CompSci graduates I've encountered are rather bad at programming (To the point that even a junior position is stretching it). They are different fields with different focuses. Sure a physicist can do an engineers job, but no way near as well...

Comment: @ircmaxwell: I think my point is that people in the field should be expert at both, not one or the other.

Comment: @Gordon: Read it before, amusing.

Comment: @Pekka: You don't need to be a mathematical genius to program, but you do need to be highly competent.  Otherwise you *will* run in to trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `echo` goes outside of it, not in, it (the ternary operator) is returning a value, not a codeblock.

```
<?php echo ($users['active'] == 1 ? "Yes" : "No"); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun a different way:

```
$msg = array(true => 'Yes', false => 'No');
echo $msg[(users['active'] == 1)];
```

Comment: Agreed, it was a sensible suggestion, illustrating a good method to use when there are multiple options. +1

Comment: +1 for showing an alternative and not actually suggesting it. :)

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar: I didn't expect up votes for this ;) But as @Orbling said, if there are more than two options, using this kind of map is often better (as easier to maintain) than `if-else` or `switch` constructs...

Answer (score 0):

```
<? if ($users['active']): ?>Yes<? else: ?>No<? endif ?>
```

Comment: Do you seriously think that is better than a ternary? :-|

Comment: I was a little confused about this for a moment but then realized what it does. :P

Comment: Since this is echoing something, Col. is assuming you are in a template context so yes, it's more correct this way. It probably needs some explanation tho ;-)

Comment: Sure I do. Much better. It's dividing PHP and HTML, it's more readable and it's more familiar as being regular condition for PHP templates.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I don't see any HTML in the OP's code. Maybe he is writing a shell script. Btw. echoing *data* is ok.

Comment: @Col. thanks for suggesting the alternative but personally i would prefer the above solution because i thinks that is more readable..

Comment: @Felix Kling shell scripts could use templates too ;-)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Obviously it is just my opinion, but I think it is substantially less readable.  Also `endif` is not standard PHP.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Using that [alternative block style](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) is not standard, makes the code more label orientated like a lower-order language and moves away from the C-style roots of the language.

Comment: @Orbling define "standard" please.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: What is "usually used by the majority" for most languages.  In the case of PHP, there are a couple of defined style guides.  The [Zend Framework Coding Standard](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.control-statements.if-else-elseif), which most professionals tend to conform to, or the [PEAR coding standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.control.php).  Note both use the brace style.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The PEAR standards define [multi-line styles for ternary operators](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/rfc.cs-enhancements.ternaryoperators.php).

Comment: Well, I an not using Zend standard then.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Zend are the language developers, so their standard is bound to be the commonplace.  I imagine the alternative style is to appease people coming from a VB background or somesuch.

Comment: So be it. I am from a VB background or somesuch. Hope it satisfied you enough